# django edit forms dont keep values

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a create a simple Django forms for `add` and and `edit` forms.
my problem is in  people field where I use `ModelChoiceField`.

in edit forms all values parse correct except that field `ModelChoiceField`.
In edit forms that field is empty and don't keep values ,any idea why ??

```
def edit_work(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(work, id=pk)
    form = workForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        note = form.save(commit=False)
        note.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/work/success/')
    return render(request,'edit_work.html', {'form': form})


 def add_work(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = workForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             note = form.save(commit=False)
             note.save()
             return render(request, "succes/erga_success.html")
     else:
         form = workForm()
     return render(request, 'add_work.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class workForm(forms.ModelForm):
    peaople=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),required=False, error_messages={
            'invalid': _("---")})
    class Meta:
        model = work
        fields = (__all__")
```

html page :

```
     <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
     {{form.peaople}}
     .........
     <input type="submit" value="create">
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is not being kept because you are not saving it anywhere, not assigning it.

1. Save the value somewhere.

```
# views.py

# in both view functions
if form.is_valid():
    note = form.save(commit=False)
    note.save()
    somemodel.people = form.cleaned_data.get("people")
    somemodel.save()
```

2. Initialize the form with the saved value

```
def edit_work(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(work, id=pk)
    form = workForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance, initial={'people': somemodel.people})
    if form.is_valid():
        note = form.save(commit=False)
        note.save()
        somemodel.people = form.cleaned_data.get("people")
        somemodel.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/work/success/')
    return render(request,'edit_work.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: my values save works fine I can see in details template and in database

Comment: Did you try initializing the form with the saved value?

Comment: Gang yes I can see the saved value

Comment: Then what exactly is the issue?

Comment: look the save in add form work fine , but if I try to use edit form then only that field is empty don't parse the value in edit form if I use ModelChoiceField .

Comment: if I use in edit forms people= instance.people I take correct value

Answer (score 0):

Why are you manually specifying `peaople` field? Maybe this data is not saved under  WorkModel.peaople field and is manually saved elsewhere? Considering that `ModelChoiceField` is for single value, then most likely that field is ForeignKey
 and named differently (not `peaople`): if custom field of a ModelForm does not match field with the same name on a model, then it's not populated by default.

Possible solutions:

- If model field name differs to field on model, then you should pass `initial={'peaople': instance.some_human_fk_field}` argument when you are initializing form.
- If you only need to change the widget/label/error_message, etc of some existing model field (e.g. `some_human_fk_field`) to be `ModelChoiceField, 'people', {'invalid': _("---")}` then you [don't need to define custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) at all:

```py
class workForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = work
        fields = ("__all__")
        labels = {
            'some_human_fk_field': _('People'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'some_human_fk_field': {
                'invalid': _("---"),
            },
        }
        field_classes = {
            'some_human_fk_field': forms.ModelChoiceField,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(workForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['some_human_fk_field'].queryset = User.objects.all()
        # Or you can dynamically determine queryset, for example you want to accout 'Work.owner.company' field: 
        # limiting_factor = None
        # if self.instance.pk:
        #     limiting_factor = self.instance.owner.company
        # elif self.data:
        #     _owner_pk = self.data.get('owner')
        #     limiting_factor = Company.objects.get(owners_set__pk=_owner_pk)
        # elif self.initial and self.initial.get('owner'):
        #     limiting_factor = self.initial['owner'].company

        # if limiting_factor:
        #     self.fields['some_human_fk_field'].queryset = build_qs_from_limiting_factor(
        #         User.objects.all(),
        #         company=limiting_factor
        #     )
        # else:
        #     self.fields['some_human_fk_field'].queryset = User.objects.all()
```

- If your `peaople` field on a `work` model is not an FK (e.g. a TextField), then you need to "manually set" `field.initial` after form initialization:

```py
class workForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(workForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk and self.instance.peaople:
            self.fields['peaople'].initial = User.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.peaople)  # or `username=self.instance.peaople` depending on what you are really saving there
```

Comment: I'm sorry because it was my fault that I did not mention it earlier The people field is a textfield and not fk .just I want to choose some user name,i try to use choose field for modelfield but don't show me empty option to select because that is some option field

Comment: if it's a text field then you should change `initial` parameter of a field in the `workForm.__init__` after call to `super().__init_(...)`: `if self.instance and self.instance.peaople: self.fields['peaople'].initial = User.objects.filter(pk=int(self.instance.peaople)).first()`